# Why does my pattern discontinue on non-user line breaks?

Tags: ios, regex, icu

I'm trying to parse an ics calendar files description like so
[image]

For PCRE this works fine but when I try and convert this for iOS/ICU use I get the following result:

```
let descriptionRegex = "(?m)DESCRIPTION:(.*(?:\\n :?.*)*)"
```

*Returns:* `"What is the purpose of the stand up meeting? \nIt is a 15 "`

When converting this to an ICU expression what change have I failed to account for?

Original Text:

```
DESCRIPTION:The purpose of a retrospective meeting is to reflect on th
 e previous sprint together with the development team to learn from our
  mistakes. \nIs the team performing well or what can we do to improve 
 our way of working\, our efficiency\, and so on. \nAny topic can be di
 scussed\, we strive for open communication in this meeting to continuo
 usly improve as a team. \n\nWe try to list: \n - Engine
 : what is working well and what do we continue doing? \n - Anchor
 : what didn't we do well or what went wrong\, so what do we stop doing
  or can be improved? \n - Try
 : which actions do we take\, which things do we try in the next sprint
  to improve? \n\nAfter the retrospective\, I want to have a look at th
 e sprint plan\, to decide which user stories we work on next with the 
 team.
```

Comment: Aren't you just looking for any text from `DESCRIPTION` up to the ALLCAPS word that starts a line below? Use [`(?ms)^DESCRIPTION:(.*?)(?=^[A-Z]+:)`](https://regex101.com/r/rD8hV5/1). Or better: [`(?m)^DESCRIPTION:([^\n]*(?:\n++(?![A-Z]+:)[^\n]*)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/rD8hV5/2).

Comment: True I'm working on that at the moment. Although yours looks a bit better than my own. I'm mostly curious as to why this doesn't work so I can better understand ICU parsing in future.
https://regex101.com/r/iH9kP7/5

Comment: I do not understand: `(?m)^DESCRIPTION:(.*(?:\n :?.*)*)` should work well in iOS. Could you show the testing code?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Unfortunately it doesn't. I've put it in to an ICU parser as well which also shows it to be working. I've just tried your 2nd one (nice efficiency btw) and it works. Thanks, feel free to put it as an answer.

Comment: You know, I am rather unsure as to what whitespace your string contains. IMHO, each question concerning whitespace should contain a piece of code with the real test string - I am just not sure if `\n` is a literal ``\`` and `n` or a line feed. Also, ICU has a support for `\R` (newline sequence), you might try using it, too (in swift string, `\\R`)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've added the original text. I'm only just starting to realise there's different types of line break which is likely the root issue here.

Comment: I think it's only a copy/paste problem or something that gets wrong when you declare your string because `\n` in your source string are a literal backslash and a literal `n`, not newline characters *(as you can see the newlines before LOCATION and SUMMARY are not displayed as `\n`)*. Once this problem solved, something like `(?m)^DESCRIPTION:(.*)` should suffice.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I found out why these \n literals were leaking in to my export. I'd exported from what was originally a windows application that uses \r\n for its line breaks. When I pasted this in to a mac text editor or viewed it within the xcode console the \r was all that was needed to linebreak so the literal \n was left behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may turn out that you have different newline sequences in your file (`\r` or `\r\n` or just `\n`, or even mixed). Thus, you can try replacing `\n` in your regex with `\R`.

Also, in case you want to match some unknown number of characters between some delimiters, you can use `(?s)DEL1(.*?)(?=DEL2)` regex that can be unrolled to achieve better performance depending on the `DEL2` delimiter.

Here is one for your scenario:

```
(?m)^DESCRIPTION:([^\n]*(?:\n++(?![A-Z]+:)[^\n]*)*)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rD8hV5/2)

The `[^\n]*(?:\n++(?![A-Z]+:)[^\n]*)*` part is an unrolled version of `(?ms).*?(?=^[A-Z]+:)`. The **advantage of an unrolled regex** is that **it does not depend on a DOTALL modifer**. It may match across multiple lines. Also, performance is usually much better compared to lazy dot matching pattern.